# How to avoid conditional multiple SELECT in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this simple SQL

```
SELECT 
(CASE
    WHEN
        (SELECT 
                Name
            FROM
                Customers
            WHERE
                Customers_id = Customer) IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        (SELECT 
                Name
            FROM
                Customers
            WHERE
                Customers_id = Customer)
    ELSE Customer
END) AS Customer,
DateStart,
ProgramsRun.Programs_id,
RunInSeconds,
SwSQL,
SwProgram,
Name AS ProgramName
FROM
ProgramsRun
    LEFT JOIN
Programs ON ProgramsRun.Programs_id = Programs.Programs_id;
```

My question is how can I avoid make two same SELECT statements: one as condition and other as a value selection. I know that I can create a temporary variable, but this forces me to use stored procedures or temporary tables. Is there a simple way to avoid this?

Comment: where does `Customer` come from ? From Programs ? From ProgramRuns ? Else ?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid it?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Customer is a column in table ProgramsRun. It contains an ID of the customer. There's another table called Customers where you can find a "common name" of the customer by it's id (Customers_id and Name). The goal is to select Customer_id in column Customer when there's NO common name specified, and display it's common name when there IS a common name record present in table Customers

Comment: @BartFriederichs I would like to avoid it because actually you're selecting two times same thing: once to check it's nulity and second select is as a value. In my opinion there should be only one select for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `IFNULL` like this:

```
IFNULL((SELECT 
                Name
            FROM
                Customers
            WHERE
                Customers_id = Customer),Customer)
```

Or `COALESCE` like this:

```
COALESCE((SELECT 
                Name
            FROM
                Customers
            WHERE
                Customers_id = Customer),Customer)
```

Reference:

- [COALESCE(value,...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)
- [IFNULL(expr1,expr2)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Comment: Thank you, it worked, although you forgot to put one more  parenthesis in front of IFNULL, so the last expression would be like IFNULL((SELECT 
                Name
            FROM
                Customers
            WHERE
                Customers_id = Customer),Customer) AS Customer,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
 IsNull(Name,Customer)
AS Customer,
DateStart,
ProgramsRun.Programs_id,
RunInSeconds,
SwSQL,
SwProgram,
Name AS ProgramName
FROM
ProgramsRun
    LEFT JOIN
Programs ON ProgramsRun.Programs_id = Programs.Programs_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your query by using join

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(c.Name,Customer) AS Customer,
DateStart,
ProgramsRun.Programs_id,
RunInSeconds,
SwSQL,
SwProgram,
Programs.`Name` AS ProgramName
FROM ProgramsRun
LEFT JOIN Programs ON ProgramsRun.Programs_id = Programs.Programs_id
LEFT JOIN Customers c ON c.Customers_id = Customer;
```